# How to mange scenario of syncing on-prem SSO database and Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have the following scenario:

- On-prem SQL SSO database exists that manages usernames and password (salted and hashed).
- Azure AD B2C in the cloud for local accounts (usernames and passwords).

I would like to have both systems stay in sync. So, when a user requests a password reset from the on-prem SSO database, it will salt and hash the password, and then transmit that password to Azure AD B2C. Similarly, if the user requests a password reset from Azure AD B2C it will salt and hash that password back down to the on-prem database as well, if possible; I can imagine a scenario where this simply isn't possible in which case it would be OK if the hash value of the password is stored and we can assign a secondary column for "authentication_method" which will allow other client apps to still authenticate. If a new user signs-up on either side, then the appropriate record is created in both systems for local accounts only.

How can I go about implementing such a flow? What kind of documentation would be helpful here from the AD B2C side? Are there other synchronization tools available for this scenario?

I can imagine something like Apache Kafka or some script to sync data back and forth, but I am not sure about the specifics on the B2C side of how to get the password. I'm sure I've seen some documentation on how to update the user's password for the first scenario of on-prem to cloud, but lack information on how to go from cloud to on-prem.

The purpose of this is to support a newer application to leverage B2C, but still allow older apps to work without having to update them to B2C.

Answer (score 1):

Password HashSync to Azure AD B2C is not supported. There are a couple of moving parts in your scenario that needs to be addressed.

1. The Azure AD B2C to SSO Database: You can use REST-API that Azure B2C [custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/rest-api-claims-exchange-dotnet) calls from its custom policy, which acts as a broker to authenticate (username, password). Since you are using local accounts with Azure AD B2C this should work as long as your backend can authenticate the user using username/password. There is no sync needed but until the SSO database goes away you need to keep using the REST-API. Essentially, you want to use a single source of truth. This approach is similar to the pattern describe [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/tree/master/jit-migration-v1).
2. On the Azure AD B2C side, you can update the password for a local user account using [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). This opens up the door to update the password from your on-prem system to Azure AD B2C as needed. Of course, Azure AD B2C hash the password itself but you don't have access to it.

Either way, you need to evaluate the pros and cons.